# Is the closure of compact still compact in this space?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $(X,T)$ be topological space such that such that every sequence has at most one point limit point. I am trying to check the following

> the closure of compact set in $X$ is still compact. Is true or not ?

I am trying to find a counter example but I could not. Maybe is true so I need to prove it. Any help ?

Comment: [This](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/106571/a-space-in-which-sequences-have-unique-limits-but-compact-sets-need-not-be-close) is related, and may give some ideas.

Comment: There probably is some counterexample. Sequences that converge have little to do with compactness or closure in general spaces. There are US spaces that are not KC. But the standard exemples there don't work for this (by coincidence). So modify those.. See Mitra's link.

Comment: @Gob , if $(X, \tau) $ is hausdorff, then closure of compact set is compact but it is not difficult to find a compact set in a non hausdorff space whose closure is not compact. I think one of my question might help you https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4315044/977780

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, I did not how easy can I modify the example. Do you any suggestion

Comment: The orginal question would be slighty more clear if it referred to every convergent sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a counterexample.

Modifying an old example [F] on the link reference by David Mitra.

Start with [0,1].

Attach new points $z_1, z_2,..$ so that a typical neighborhood of $z_n$ is the the union of $z_n$ and also an open dense subset of the open interval $(1/(n+1),1/n)$.

A) The resulting space is not compact, since the open cover V1,V2,... so that $z_n \in V_n$, and $z_m$ is not in $V_n$ if $n\neq m$, has no finite subcover.

B) [0,1] is dense in the new space, since each nbhd of each $z_n$ contains a nonempty open subset of [0,1].

C) [0,1] remains a compact subspace of the new space since our new open sets are open in the original space [0,1]

D) Convergent sequences in the new space have unique limits.